# How to use `mat-select` component when focused by TAB key?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to make an input element focusable. I mean user should be able to use this field to filter values using only keyboard.
I added tabindex however it behaves strange.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-db2km6-5a83e7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### TLDR: Check [this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-db2km6-uekftg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts) which lets you write and search just after the select is focused by using the TAB key.

---

The [`mat-select`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect) component only focuses the element, it doesn't the input nor it opens the inner search field to filter its values.

To achieve that, you need do it manually. The main changes in the working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-db2km6-uekftg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts) I provided are the following:

**HTML:**

```html
<!-- 1. Added the id #field to reference the component later -->
<!-- 2. Added event `openAndSearch(field, multiUserSearch)` to fix the logic for the expected focus -->
<mat-select
  #field
  multiple
  [formControl]="providers"
  (openedChange)="onOpenChange(multiUserSearch)"
  (focus)="openAndSearch(field, multiUserSearch)"
>...</..>
```

**TS:**

```js
/**
 * Method to be executed when focus is triggered
 **/
openAndSearch(field: MatSelect, input: HTMLInputElement) {
  // Open and show the list of options
  field.open();
  // Focus the search input so the user can type directly
  setTimeout(() => { // <-- inside timeout to wait for the overlay to show up
    input.focus();
  }, 10);
}
```